# htaccess block access to subfolder without existence of cookie

Tags: .htaccess

I´m trying to allow access to `data/party/*` only for users with a certain cookie. Therefore I´ve extended my .htaccess in root dir. The last part should check URI for the subfolder and the existence of a cookie. Unfortunately it´s not blocking access. Important: I´d like to have the .htaccess in webroot not in the subfolder `data/party`. mod_rewrite is enabled. thanks for help!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(app|dict|ns|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}_%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!\.?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+?)_https?://.*\1/.*$"
RewriteRule \.(woff|eot|ttf|svg|woff2|otf)$ - [F,NC,L]

# NOT WORKING
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^data/party
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !AllowDataAccess=YesYouCanBoogie
RewriteRule .* - [L,F]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `/` in the condition. REQUEST_URI starts with a leading slash. So it's currently not matching.

Try it this way.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/data/party [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !AllowDataAccess=YesYouCanBoogie;? [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L,F]
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I did `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/data/party [NC]` but still can view content

Comment: I made a small tweak to the cookie condition. See if that helps. Also try to use the same case as the cookies.

Comment: mh mh mh unfortuantely not. what is strange that it´s working when I put it in party dir and reference as `/party` it´s seems the subdir rule is not catching from route ;(

Comment: It should work. Try putting the rule above your other rules under rewriteengine and update the condition to `^/data/party(/*)?`

Comment: Panama Jack sorry. the cache tricked me. its working like you suggested but I had to put before all other rules (?) anyway thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !AllowDataAccess=YesYouCanBoogie
RewriteRule ^data/party - [L,F]
```

or you can change your `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/data/party`
with `^/`

Comment: I tried both, but still get access to the content without cookie ;(